# Servlet-mapping glitch with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-mapping

​If I try:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I get this error:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/sample/WEB-INF/jsp/person.jsp]
```

If I try just `/` as `<url-pattern>` then everything works fine.

My url : `http://localhost:8080/sample/person`

Why is this happening? What is the preferred way of doing this configuration in web.xml?

My `app-servlet.xml` has :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How have you configured your application to locate the *.jsp files? Can you please put in your resourcing configuration setup?

Answer (score 2):

You mapped /* (every request to your app) to your servlet called 'app'. The InternalResourceViewResolver than looks (internally) for '/person' inside '/WEB-INF/jsp/person.jsp'. This way you can access your views, while the scripts are secured inside WEB-INF, which is not accessible from the url (public).

Answer (score 1):

`/*` means every public request to your web-app. It means for your jsp it should be public accessed, since it is in WEB-INF and not public it will give error.

If you use only `/` it means server took the request and the web-app processes it internal without any public access.